# Solve a fraction without any operator in the denominator

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

(Skip to the last paragraph if you don't want the context)

I'm working on a program where I need to deal with big numbers (10,000,000+), and I need fractions. Computers lose accuracy when doing mathematical operations on fractions the bigger the fraction is, due to the way numbers are stored.

I'm working on a data type that uses a 64-bit integer and a 32-bit floating point number. I'm currently working on implementing the binary operators for this data type and I've hit a major roadblock.

I'm storing the number, which I'll call $BigNumber$ for the remainder of this question, such that we have two parts: $a$ and $b$, where $a$ is an integer and $b$ is a fraction between $0$ and $1$. When multiplying $BigNumber$ $x$ with $BigNumber$ $y$, we have $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, where $a$ is $BigNumber$ $x$'s integer, $b$ is $BigNumber$ $x$'s fraction, $c$ is $BigNumber$ $y$'s integer and $d$ is $BigNumber$ $z$'s fraction. I can add two integers together, add two fractions together, but cannot add any integer to any fraction (this will make me lose accuracy).

I cannot use any operator other than the binary operators (for performance, the program is a videogame).

I'm currently stuck on calculating the division operator. I've got multiplication, but even though $\frac{a}{b} \equiv a \times \frac{1}{b}$, it still has a division operation, which is what I'm trying to implement.

Basically solve $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ such that you can only have **one** number on the denomator of **any** fraction. You can **only** use binary operators (+, -, $\times$, $\div$) and % (remainder of a division, for example $5$ % $3 = 2$). $a, c$ $\in \Bbb Z$, $b$ and $d$ are a value between $0$ and $1$

Comment: Can you show how you got multiplication? At the moment, it looks like you can do: (1) $x \leftarrow a+ b$; (2) $y \leftarrow c + d$; (3) $z \leftarrow x \div y$.

Comment: By multiplication, I mean I can multiply any pair of $BigNumber$ together

Comment: yes, I meant, can you show how you did that? I think it would make the requirements you are trying to explain clearer. In particular, I'm confused about this sentence "such that you can only have one number on the denomator of any fraction."

Comment: @roundsquare https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/678699507986333766/680146100640153640/unknown.png

Comment: What you are talking about is not "fractions", which refers to the ratios of integers, but "fixed point arithmetic" with 64 bits before the decimal, and some number of bits behind (using a floating point allows for some variance here). By searching for the correct terminology, you can find how this problem has been solved before (and it has been solved numerous times - basically it just long division from grade school). Note that any time you multiply or divide, you still lose some information because it isn't completely representable by the floating point variable.